# How to create a sort function that will work with different properties of my user model

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I am currently rendering my user list using the below functions in my reactjs app.

I want to somehow create a generic sort function where I can sort my users by different properties that are on the user object:

```
User
-id
-sortOrder
-dateCreated
-name
```

**Is it possible to write a sort function that I could then sort by either the id, sortOrder, dateCreated or name properties?**

```
_renderUsers() {
  const { users, dispatch } = this.props;
  return users.map((user) => {
    return (
        <User
          key={user.id}
          dispatch={dispatch}
          {...user}          
        />
      );
  });
}
```

which I call in my main render function:

```
<div className="users-list">
  {::this._renderUsers()}
</div>
```

Comment: Sure, you can provide a function to the native sort method if you wish, and use that function to compare the particular property. Wrap that in your _renderUsers method that accespt that property as a string.

Comment: Did any of the answers work for you? Consider accepting one of them if that's the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

version with a little more flexibility on direction and numeric sorting

```js
const users = [
  { id: 4, sortOrder: "asc", dateCreated: "2016-01-01", name: "Foo" },
  { id: 2, sortOrder: "desc", dateCreated: "2014-01-01", name: "Bar" },
  { id: 1, sortOrder: "desc", dateCreated: "2015-01-01", name: "Test" }
];

function sortArr(arr, key, ascending = true) {
  if (!isNaN(arr[0][key])) {
    return arr.sort((a, b) => (ascending ? a[key] - b[key] : b[key] - a[key]))
  } else {
    return arr.sort((a, b) => {
      const ref = ascending ? a[key] : b[key];
      const comp = ascending ? b[key] : a[key];
      return ref.localeCompare(comp);
    });
  }
}

LOG(sortArr(users, 'name', false)) // string names descending
LOG(sortArr(users, 'id')) // numeric id ascending

function LOG(d) {
  console.log(JSON.stringify(d, null, ' '));
  console.log('\n*******************************\n')
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could create a function that takes the `users` array and a string `sortParam` indicating which parameter to use for sorting them.

```js
const users = [
  { id: 4, sortOrder: "asc", dateCreated: "2016-01-01", name: "Foo" },
  { id: 2, sortOrder: "desc", dateCreated: "2014-01-01", name: "Bar" },
  { id: 1, sortOrder: "desc", dateCreated: "2015-01-01", name: "Test" }
];

function sortUsers(users, sortParam) {
  return users.sort((a, b) => {
    if (a[sortParam] < b[sortParam]) {
      return -1;
    }
    if (a[sortParam] > b[sortParam]) {
      return 1;
    }
    return 0;
  });
}

console.log(sortUsers(users, 'id'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an approach which allows you to use the `localeCompare` with any field:

```js
var users = [
{
 id: 1,
 name: 'Bob',
 age: 13,
 state: 'CA',
 other: 'james1'
},
{
 id: 2,
 name: 'Ken',
 age: 23,
 state: 'AL',
 other: 'james11'
},{
 id: 3,
 name: 'Alex',
 age: 33,
 state: 'NY',
 other: 'kin 1'
},
{
 id: 4,
 name: 'Alex',
 age: 83,
 state: 'DC',
 other: 'kin 110'
}
]

const sortBy = (array, field, options={ direction: 'asc' }) => 
 array.sort((x,y) => (options.direction == 'desc' ? -1 : 1) * String(x[field]).localeCompare(String(y[field]), undefined, options))

console.log(sortBy(users, 'name'))   // just by name
console.log(sortBy(users, 'state', { direction: 'desc' })) // change the direction
console.log(sortBy(users, 'age', { numeric: true })) // sorting numbers
console.log(sortBy(users, 'other', { numeric: true })) // notice how "other" values are ordered now
```

What this allows you is to pass [options object to localeCompare](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare) and as well change direction of the final order. Comparing numbers/numbers in strings etc is possible with this.

To change the sort order we just multiply by `-1` or `1` (depending on the desired direction) the result of `localeCompare`.

The price to pay here is the `boxing to String` in order to use `localeCompare`.